# plot several subplots in IPython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have two sets of 8 images each given as numpy arrays.

Because I want to use a for loop at some point in my program, I want to display each set as matplotlib subplots in the same cell, unfortunately it does not work (I tried to use the display function from IPython.display, with no success at all).

Here is the code I used :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

for i, img in enumerate(set1):
    plt.subplot(2, 4, i+1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(img)

for i, img in enumerate(set2):
    plt.subplot(2, 4, i+1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(img)
```

It only displays the second set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that you are plotting everything on the same figure. Therefore, when plotting images from `set2` you are overwriting the images from `set1`. You can create a new figure by calling `plt.figure()` before your for loops:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

plt.figure()
for i, img in enumerate(set1):
    plt.subplot(2, 4, i+1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(img)

plt.figure()
for i, img in enumerate(set2):
    plt.subplot(2, 4, i+1)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: I see ! Thanks a lot for your answer.